# Show that $S = (-1)^X$ is the UMVUE of $e^{-2\mu}$

Tags: probability, statistical-inference

If $X \sim POI(\mu)$, show that $S = (-1)^X$ is the UMVUE of $e^{-2\mu}$.  Is this a reasonable estimator?

UMVUE stands for uniformly minimum-variance unbiased estimator

The pdf of the Poisson distribution is $P\left( x \right) = \frac{{e^{ - \mu} \mu^x }}{{x!}}$

How would you do this problem?

Comment: Maybe you should mention that UMVUE stands for "uniformly minimum-variance unbiased estimator". But you definitely should define "reasonable estimator", because without that, it isn't even a question, and thus there will be no answer.

Comment: I'm not sure myself what an "reasonable estimator" in the question really mean.  I think it means is it accurate?  Would this estimator gives me strange estimates such as a negative value?

Comment: It's the **only** unbiased estimator, so... Have in mind that this is an estimator **based on a single observation**, and how reasonable can statistics with sample size 1 be to begin with? If you have $n$ independent observations $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, $S_n=X_1+\ldots+X_n$ is a (complete) sufficient statistic, so $E((-1)^{X_1}|S_n)$ would be optimal, and that's not hard to calculate.

Comment: (Un-)"reasonable" here obviously refers to the fact that the estimator is negative with positive probability although the quantity it is supposed to estimate is positive. Now that this is clarified, please explain what you tried to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to see that $(-1)^X$ is the only unbiased estimator: if $f(X)$ is an unbiased estimator,
$$Ef(X)=\sum^\infty_{k=0}f(k)P(X=k)=e^{-\mu}\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{f(k)}{k!}\mu^k=e^{-2\mu}$$implies
$$\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{f(k)}{k!}\mu^k=e^{-\mu}=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\mu^k,$$ so we must have $f(k)=(-1)^k$ by the uniqueness theorem for power series.
Of course, it's an estimator as poor as one can expect from sample size $1$. If we have $n$ independent $X_i \sim POI(\mu)$, we can easily see that $\displaystyle S_n=\sum^n_{i=1}X_i$ is a sufficient statistic, so $E((-1)^{X_1}|S_n)$ would be the UMVUE. That's not hard to calculate, along the same lines as in the example in the Wikipedia article about the [Rao–Blackwell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rao%E2%80%93Blackwell_theorem), but that's not really necessary: for $X \sim POI(\mu)$, we have $\displaystyle E\alpha^X=e^{(\alpha-1)\mu}$ (the above is the special case $\alpha=-1$). Now $S_n \sim POI(n\mu)$, so $\displaystyle E\alpha^{S_n}=e^{(\alpha-1)n\mu}=e^{-2\mu}$ exactly for $\displaystyle\alpha=1-\frac2n$, i.e. our estimator is $$f(S_n)=\left(1-\frac2n\right)^{S_n},$$ looking far more reasonable, especially since with $n\to\infty$, $\displaystyle\left(1-\frac2n\right)^n\to e^{-2}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{S_n}n\to\mu$ a.s. according to the strong law of large numbers, and thus $\displaystyle f(S_n)\to e^{-2\mu}$ a.s.